# How to hook to a function to iOS alarms?

Tags: objective-c, ios7, tweak, cydia-substrate

I'm trying to use Theos in order to hook up and capture the names of the alarms that have been stopped.

I have done this:

```
// Logos by Dustin Howett
// See http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/Logos
//#import <SpringBoard/SpringBoard.h>
#import <MobileTimer/AlarmManager.h>
//#import <SpringBoard/SBApplicationIcon.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
//#import <SpringBoard/SBRemoteNotificationEnableSystemwideAlert.h>

%hook AlarmManager

- (void)handleAlarm:(id)arg1 stoppedUsingSong:(id)arg2 {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"ALARM!!!!" message:@"HELLO!!!" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    %orig(arg1,arg2);
}
%end
```

The problem is that I never see the alertbox. Do you have any ideas why this is?

Answer (score 0):

After `[alert show];` put `[alert release];`
 This:

```
%hook AlarmManager 
    - (void)handleAlarm:(id)arg1 stoppedUsingSong:(id)arg2 {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"ALARM!!!!" message:@"HELLO!!!" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
    %orig(arg1,arg2);
}
%end
```

Comment: So does that mean that when I use Logos there is not ARC support? Also I can't test the code right now. I'll do it today and report back. Are you sure this is the correct method to hook onto because I tried it with NSLog instead of UIAlertView and nothing was put inside the console?

Comment: Then the handle alarm weren't called. Are you sure about it is arg1 arg2 and not fp8 fp12 (I never saw arg1 arg2 on any dumped header, maybe I just didn't noticed them). Try to call the method manualy from applicationDidBecome, and watch the logs

Comment: As far as I got it the argument names don't matter because I'm referencing them when passing to the original %orig method. Am I correct on this one?